# Excel cut Initials out of a Profilename and show it as full name in another Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a datasheet in Excel with 154 Columns. A is with a profile name for example like this:

**T_Data_Capture_CustomerData_(jp)**

What I want to do is make a new Column with the full name of the Author from the initials that are in the profile name **_(jp)** (example Johnson, Paul).

Now I have multiple profiles here, with different people and their initials like: **(ss),(mwp),(an)**  etc and I also have the Full Names of the Author and their initials as a seperate Datasheet from which I can read the data from.

Also the profile names don't all start the same, they are different in lenght, examples:

**P_V8_Intersport_I_WE_IBD_AVIS_SAVE_XRange_(mi)
P_DSV-DM_Fortras-Release-6_BORD128_to_ALFLAT-ALBORD_(ak)
P_V4_100_Gardner_Denver_Credit_to_ALINVOICE_Part_01_Processing_Of_Data_(ss)**

It would look something like this:

| Profile name | Author |
| --- | --- |
| T_Data_Capture_CustomerData_(jp) | Johnson, Paul |
| P_V8_Intersport_I_WE_IBD_AVIS_SAVE_XRange_(ss) | Smith, Sophie |

I just don't really know how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'd need a lookup range, a place where you could link these abbreviations to the full profile names. If so, then it's just a matter of a combination of functions to retrieve the abbreviations. Which functions would depend on your version of Excel. Can you include that information, including your own attempt at solving this since it's off-topic to just ask for help/a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, simple, but the first one relies on the initials being in the last 3 characters:

```
VLOOKUP(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,3),2),E2:F3,2,0)
```

[image]

If you want more characters then you can use mid() with find() to locate the ( as the start and ) as the end. Like so:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion I`ll try this out. I wanted to state that the the profile names have different lengths, which means the the initials do not start all at the same spot, that makes then the first suggestion obsolete.

Comment: @Jovan you did see in the first line that I said the initials needed to be in the last 3 characters... But as you gave so few examples - they all showed the last 3 characters was relevant as an assumption. But my second version deals with that anyway, unless you are now going to suggest some initials have curly brackets etc.

Comment: yes I have seen it, I've edited my question to be a bit more in depth and precisely what I want to achieve. The VLOOKUP might work, I'll have to test it out.

Comment: @Jovan So you now show an example where there are two in the same text string. You can search on here as there are solutions to that as well.

Comment: The VLOOKUP suggestion worked perfectly, I was struggling a bit as the Formatting for Excel was in EU form and so the separators and others were completely different and my Excel is in German because of my Organization. I'll post my function as maybe someone will find it perhaps helpful in my format:
=VERWEIS(TEIL(C3;FINDEN("(";C3)+1;FINDEN(")";C3)-FINDEN("(";C3)-1);J7;A2:A101:B2:101)

Comment: @Jovan most of us are used to swapping “,” for “;” between functions just a system thing really. But happy it works for you.

Comment: Oops I made a mistake, this is the right function:
=VERWEIS(TEIL(C2;FINDEN("(";C2)+1;FINDEN(")";C2)-FINDEN("(";C2)-1);A2:A101:B2:B101)
But yeah I'll just leave it as it. Thanks again!